# SAT/CNF optimization

Tags: algorithm, optimization, linear-programming, satisfiability

### Problem

I'm looking at a special subset of SAT optimization problem. For those not familiar with SAT and related topics, here's the [related Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_satisfiability_problem).

```
TRUE=(a OR b OR c OR d) AND (a OR f) AND ...
```

There are no NOTs and it's in conjunctive normal form. This is easily solvable. However I'm trying **to minimize the number of true assignments** to make the whole statement true. I couldn't find a way to solve that problem.

### Possible solutions

I came up with the following ways to solve it:

1. Convert to a directed graph and search the minimum spanning tree, spanning only a subset of vertices. There's Edmond's algorithm but that gives a MST for the complete graph instead of a subset of the vertices.

   - Maybe there's a version of Edmond's algorithm that solves the problem for a subset of the vertices?
   - Maybe there's a way to construct a graph out of the original problem that's solvable with other algorithms?
2. Use a SAT solver, a LIP solver or exhaustive search. I'm not interested in those solutions as I'm trying to use this problem as lecture material.

### Question

Do you have any ideas/comments? Can you come up with other approaches that might work?

Comment: One can easily prove this problem is NP-Hard as well, because of the minimization constraint. Are you intrested in such a proof?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This problem is [NP-Hard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-hard) as well.

One can show an east reduction from [Hitting Set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hitting_set#Hitting_set_and_set_cover):

**Hitting Set problem**: Given sets `S1,S2,...,Sn` and a number `k`: chose set `S` of size `k`, such that for every `Si` there is an element `s` in `S` such that `s` is in `Si`. [alternative definition: the intersection between each `Si` and `S` is not empty].

**Reduction**: 

for an instance `(S1,...,Sn,k)` of hitting set, construct the instance of your problem: `(S'1 AND S'2 And ... S'n,k)` where `S'i` is all elements in `Si`, with OR. These elements in S'i are variables in the formula.

**proof:**

**Hitting Set -> This problem**: If there is an instance of hittins set, `S` then by assigning all of `S`'s elements with true, the formula is satisfied with `k` elements, since for every `S'i` there is some variable `v` which is in `S` and `Si` and thus also in `S'i`.

**This problem -> Hitting set**: build `S` with all elements whom assigment is true [same idea as Hitting Set->This problem].

Since you are looking for the optimization problem for this, it is also NP-Hard, and if you are looking for an exact solution - you should try an exponential algorithm

Comment: Wow... Now that's a proper answer! Thank you very much. Now that you described it it seems obvious.